# Getting started with Facebook application Development with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

I want to get started with facebook application development using PHP. PHP is ok, i've been using it for number of years. There are lots of tutorial online and many of these are outdated because facebook API changes, so if you have a link for a good tutorial, then it would be nice if you can share it.

As far as facebook apps is concerned, is it possible to design an application completly standalone in PHP then integrate facebook in it. Also, is there any PHP framework that is recommended to use for the development of facebook application development

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Facebook PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/).

It's better to follow their standards and code to migrate soon and you wont face any problem regarding outdated code.

You can get the SDK itself and some examples from [official repository on Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk).